# How to execute an executable with argument from within C program?

Tags: c, system

`int s = system("./my_prog 32");` works, but how do I bring in the argument as a variable? `int a = 32; int s = ("system %d", a);` doesn't seem to work ("too many arguments to function 'system' ".)

Comment: Use `sprintf` to create the string.

Comment: `snprintf` is almost always a better idea than `sprintf`.

Comment: @aschepler Why? Because of buffer overflow?

Answer (score 2):

The system() function in C takes a single argument of type `const char *`.  That is why your first example works (though, your second example is malformed).

Still, what you want can be achieved using the `sprintf()` function in `stdio.h`.  `int a = 32; char command[80]; sprintf(command, "./my_prog %d", a); system(command);`

Comment: @John Bollinger Beat me to the punch.  :)

Answer (score 1):

> how do I bring in the argument as a variable?

A common technique is to generate the command string dynamically, with `sprintf()`. For example:

```
char command[100];
int a = 42;
sprintf(command, "./my_prog %d", a);
int s = system(command);
```